# c# Problems assigning values to points class

Tags: c#, point

I am having difficulty assigning integers to a points class. I have a list of coords class that contain an integer for `X` and `Y` values (`Xp` and `Yp` respectively). The integer type is `Int32` and was converted from a `string` to a `double` and then to an `integer` using:

```
X = double.Parse(setX, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The minimum `X` and `Y` values in the list are deducted from each coordinate before being assigned to a point. A check showed that the calculation is performing correctly but in the points the values are all wrong. I am wondering if there is a problem with the way I am assigning using `points[n]` or if there is a better way of creating points to plot to a polygon? Sorry it is quite a length process procedure for producing the coords class, so I omitted it, but if you need more information please let me know.

```
Point[] points = new Point[coords.Count];

int n = 0;

foreach (var i in coords)
{
    //These calculations are working fine: 
    int Xp = i.Xplt - minX;
    int Yp = i.Yplt - minY;

    //However when I assign to a new point. The calculation is wrong returning 0's and the incorrect result 
    points[n] = new Point(Xp, Yp);

    n = +1;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line

```
n = +1;
```

You probably ment

```
n += 1;
```

Comment: Damn I can't believe I missed that but thanks for your answer